# ValueError: Shapes (None, 9) and (None, 22000, 9) are incompatible

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, time-series, lstm

The following is my code:
The shape of my X_train is TensorShape([600, 22000, 5])
The shape of my Y_train is (600, 9)
Is there an error with the type of data that I am using for this time-series problem?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(22000, 5)))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

#print(model.summary())
model.fit(allfileswow[:600], features_a1[:600], epochs=100,verbose=0)
```

Comment: Maybe `Flatten` between `LSTM` and `Dense`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi just like @Djinn mentioned add a flatten layer to make everything 1-D

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(22000, 5)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

Comment: When I added a flatten layer, the model is stuck and doesn’t start the first epoch. Is it maybe cuz my data is very big?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing '***return_sequences=True***' as you don't need full sequence as the output for the next layer.
Refer [lstm](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/)